# Chrome send data from background page to browser action

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I have a background page that listens in on tab changes

```
var tabHandler={


    onTabUpdate:function(tabId,  changeInfo,  tab){


    },
    tabChanged:function(activeInfo) {
        function tabChanged(tab){

        var parser = document.createElement('a');//To extract the hostname, we create dom element 
        parser.href = tab.url;

        var regex=/^(www\.)?([^\.]+)/
        var matches=regex.exec(parser.hostname)//This gives us the hostname, we extract the website name
        var website=matches[2];
        var data=getDataForWebsite(website);//Data is a json array
            //TRANSFER 'data' to Browser popup so that it can be displayed.
        }

        chrome.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabId,tabChanged);
    },

    init:function(){
        chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(this.tabChanged);

    }



}

tabHandler.init();
```

This piece of code  gets the nam of the website and fetches a list of parameters based on the website. Now that I have the data, I am wondering how to show this data in the browser action popup. I want to pass this data to the browser Action adn then parse it there to replace existing content. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4):

One thing you need to remember is that popup pages don't live while the popup is closed (unlike background pages). That means that you can't just transfer the data to the popup page since it doesn't exist anywhere at all time. Instead, whenever the popup is opened, the first thing you need to do is request the info from storage and display it however you want.

In your background page, when you receive the data for the current domain, you should save it somewhere: that could be in [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#localStorage), or [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage), or [`chrome.storage`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html) (check the documentation to see which one would make more sense in your use-case). You would want to save it indexed on the domain most likely, so that you can have the info saved from all the open tabs if needed.

Then whenever the popup is open, get the data for the current tab from the storage you used, and display the data in whichever way you want.

Comment: But what if the popup **is** still opened? How do you pass messages to it then?

Comment: You'd just use regular message passing inside your extension: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging

Answer (score 0):

You can directly access background `window` from popup by [chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getBackgroundPage).

You can also directly access popup's `window` from background when it is open by  [chrome.extension.getViews({type:'popup'})[0]](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getViews).

Using these methods you can implement a messaging between popup and background.